# rspec 2.14 very strange syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a trouble with rspec 2.14 syntax. RSpec controller work good, but it require different syntax.

```
describe Frontend::UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST "create"' do
    subject { post :create, user: { login: email } }

    context 'with valid attributes' do
      let(:email) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)[:email] }

      it { expect{ subject }.to change{ User.count }.by(1) }
      it { expect(subject).to redirect_to(root_path) }
```

Why change and redirect methods requires different syntax?

Comment: I have yet to hear a good answer for this one and I have posed the question many a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't. You could do `change(User, :count)` instead. The form you're using evaluates the block before and after running that line and checks if the value changed appropriately. In English:

- The User count is X right now.
- Call `create` in the `Frontend::UsersController`.
- The User count is Y after that.
- I expect Y to equal X + 1.

**UPDATE**

In case you're actually talking about `expect{subject}` vs. `expect(subject)`: the `change` expectation needs something to test for change *against*. Since you're passing `expect` a block, `change` knows it can first check the User count, evaluate the block (call `subject`), then check the User count again. If you didn't pass a block, it's ambiguous for when you'd actually want to start checking for changes in the User count.

Comment: I assume he means for the `subject` part.

Comment: Maybe. The answer is pretty similar in either case. I'll update with more explanation.

Comment: Many words on this subject (haha) here: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax

Comment: @zetetic your link doesn't answer the OP's question